# Change Virtual Memory

Tags: storage, lumia-550, flash-memory

Is there any way to increase the Virtual Memory size on the Windows Phone? I have a Lumia 550, with 8GB of internal storage and a 128GB SD (where I store everything).

I'd like to pump it up to 4GB or whatever is left after needed files on the internal.

Comment: You would need at minimum an interop-unlock, do you have that? It's a hack, sort of a partial jailbreak, that allows you to make a lot more changes to the phone (actually, once you have interop-unlock you can just go full root, but they may fix that at some point). Anyhow, once you have that, increasing the size of the pagefile should be easy enough (although I don't know exactly how you'd do it; I'd have to look that up).

Comment: @CBHacking cool, never heard of this! Not sure if it'll work or not, but I am going to try it.